# Why isn't my react.js web application getting displayed on my local host (vite + react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, vite

I had created a react.js web application and after closing my VScode application, I can't seem to get it to display my current progress. After installing all the node, react, and tailwind packages I ran my server with the command 'npm run dev'. I assumed that's what I would always need to type to display my app on the local server. The server runs, but it just comes out as a blank white. I tried using 'cd my-app' and then 'npm start' but I just got an error message:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages       
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:      
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-20T16_14_37_469Z-debug-0.log
```

my package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "react-tailwind-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.35",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "vite": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

Some YouTube tutorials suggested I add the start packages which I tried and didn't work so I left it the default way I found them. So my question is how do I run an existing react.js/vite that has all the packages installed but just won't display what's the command? Also, what's the difference between npm and npx commands? Note: I'm not new to JavaScript but I'm new to node, react, vite they confusing me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: _"it just comes out as a blank white"_... use your browser's dev-tools console to check for errors

Comment: You mentioned a YouTube tutorial, are you sure it's recent and you're running the same (or similar) version? Things change quickly.

Comment: @Phil they are no errors, None. It just displays a white blank page after using npm run dev

Comment: Your package.json file doesn't contain any start script, that's why you're facing this error. Instead as per your package.json, you need to run "npm run dev" this will spin up your server.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to run `npm run start`, you will get an error, because the `start` script has not been added in `package.json`.

In order for you to run your project with your current setup try typing
`npm run dev` , this will run your project in dev mode and start a dev server on `localhost`

Probably the youtuber you are watching has a custom `start` script, if you would like to add a custom script you can add it in your `scripts` json in package.json for example

```js
// other package.json stuff
"scripts":{
// other scripts...
"my-start":"vite"
}

// other package.json stuff
```

And to run your custom script simply do `npm run my-start`

The difference between `npm` and `npx`

`npm` - is a package installer, uninstaller, updater. Basically used to managed packages

`npx` - on the other hand is a package executer, meaning that you can run a package without needed to install the package

Comment: OP does say that they used `npm run dev` and it resulted in a blank page

Comment: Firstly thanks for the clarification on npm and npx. Secondly, I only used YouTube for solutions, I tried adding all that and a few other web recommendations about package.json under scrips. Nothing worked got errors, npm run dev works but the web page is blank and all my info is there I have double checked. It worked before I closed VSCode

Comment: The only things I can think of is that, there are multiple instances of vite running in the background. Maybe try restating your PC, I know vite is not that kind to windows if you are using windows.  I am sorry I cannot provide further help. One more thing that I would try is the `index.html` page if it has `<script type="module" src=".main.jsx"></script>`
Which I think it would be there by default anyway

Answer (score -1):

You are most likey running npm start in a directory without a package.json file containing the start script